# Typescript require property with certain type but any name

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a utility (a React hook) which takes an array of items.  The items can be any object but requires one property that is type number.  The specific case is I need these objects to have an index property, but the consumer of this hook can define which property this index should be.  I was hoping this could be accomplished by a utility type of some sort, maybe something like this where `IndexedProperty` would be the utility type:

Some interfaces

```
interface SomeObject {
  id: number;
  index: number;
  name: string;
}

interface AnotherObject {
  id: number;
  priority: number;
  name: string;
}
```

The hook

```
function useIndexedHook<T extends IndexedProperty>(
  items: Array<T> = []
){
  // ...
}
```

Calling the hook

```
// valid, 'index' is defined and is type number
const validItems: IndexedProperty<Array<SomeObject>, 'index'> = [ /* ... */ ];
useIndexedHook(validItems);

// valid, 'priority' is defined and is type number
const validItems2: IndexedProperty<Array<AnotherObject>, 'priority'>  = [ /* ... */ ];
useIndexedHook(validItems2);

// invalid, 'name' is defined but is type string
const invalidItems: IndexedProperty<Array<SomeObject>, 'name'> = [ /* ... */ ];
useIndexedHook(invalidItems);
```

Comment: Does https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures help?

Comment: Define a second argument in your hook, like ``` getIndex:(item:T)=>number```. So the user of the hook have to define a function that is getting the index of each item

Comment: How is `useIndexedHook` going to access this property, if it doesn't know the name of it? Remember that types don't exist at runtime...

Comment: @Thomas that is one thing I'm trying to figure out.  I don't know if this is possible or not.

Comment: One simple way is to require a getter function instead of a property: `function useIndexedHook<T>(items: T[], getter: (t: T) => string) { ... }`

Comment: @Filly/@Thomas I was hoping for something cleaner but this would work.

Comment: I don't understand how the third example is invalid. What should the type be? Is it always expecting numbers?

Comment: @sno2 not quite, the hook would need to know the name of the property as well.

Comment: @kelly  it would be invalid because the property `name` is of type string but type number is required.

Comment: Where should the error be reported? When you define the items, or when you call the hook?

Comment: @kelly I would think when you call the hook.  If you provide a list of items and define the property but that property is not valid (does not exist on object or is not of type number).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `useIndexedHook` is going to make use of this property, it will need to receive the string at runtime, not merely in its erased type signature:

```
function useIndexedHook<P extends string>(
  items: IndexedProperty<P>[],
  propertyName: P
){
  for (const item of items) {
    const propertyValue: number = item[propertyName]
  }
}
```

You can implement `IndexedProperty` like this:

```
type IndexedProperty<P extends string> = {
  [index in P]: number;
}
```

You can also substitute `Record<P, number>` if you prefer.

Usage:

```
// valid, 'index' is defined and is type number
const validItems: SomeObject[] = [ /* ... */ ];
useIndexedHook(validItems, 'index');

// valid, 'priority' is defined and is type number
const validItems2: AnotherObject[] = [ /* ... */ ];
useIndexedHook(validItems2, 'priority');

// invalid, 'name' is defined but is type string
const invalidItems: SomeObject[] = [ /* ... */ ];
useIndexedHook(invalidItems, 'name');
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-l4VikYMijxRIrBUqSoET3sNpuKjDYXMkfPIQt6w3642m80jKuTWvrUBJp3IFkDiAdoA)

Comment: This does exactly what I need and makes a lot of sense, thank you @Thomas!